# Error while running piglatin script against hadoop-2.2.0 using cassandra

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, cassandra, apache-pig

I'm trying to perform mapreduce in hadoop-2.2.0 for the data stored in cassandra using pig. I was able run the script in pig local mode but I couldn't run in mapreduce mode.Kindly help me to resolve it.Please find the stack trace for more info.

Caused by: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Found interface org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobContext, but class was expected
ERROR pigstats.SimplePigStats: ERROR: org.apache.hadoop.yarn.exceptions.ApplicationNotFoundException: Application with id 'application_1390194645126_0008' doesn't exist in RM.
Caused by: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Found interface org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobContext, but class was expected at org.apache.cassandra.hadoop.ColumnFamilyInputFormat.getSplits(ColumnFamilyInputFormat.java:103)

Answer (score 0):

The Hadoop-2 (YARN) interfaces aren't supported in the Cassandra source tree yet (see issue [CASSANDRA-5201](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-5201)). Based on the activity in that issue, it looks like this will be resolved relatively shortly. There has been some [work done out of tree to support YARN](https://github.com/michaelsembwever/cassandra-hadoop) that might work for you in the meantime. Or you could use Hadoop-1.x.